# Why is this simple VueJS component template rendering in the incorrect place within the DOM, above a table?

Tags: html, vue.js

*The examples presented below are not the actual problematic code, but as close to a simplified case as I can make it for the purposes of discussion here.*

---

**Broken Example**

The following code renders a table, but puts the Component values, unexpectedly, *above* the table element, both visually and when I inspect it in the DOM:

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="app">

    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <test></test>
        <tr><td>Y</td><td>Z</td></tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    const Test = {
      template: '<tr><td>ONE</td><td>TWO</td></tr>'
    }

    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: { Test },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Rendered output:

[image: The VueJS Component appears before the Table]

Examined DOM:

[image: DOM showing Component is above the root elements]

**A Similar Example, But Works**

However, VueJS doesn't seem to have a problem doing it with other nested objects. The following works just fine. Here's the same thing, but with a list:

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script></head>
<body>

  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li>TOP</li>
      <test></test>
      <li>BOTTOM</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>

    const Test = {
      template: '<li>MIDDLE</li>'
    }

    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: { Test },
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

At a high level, these appear to be equivalent in structure -- one container containing three items.  In the first case it's a table holding rows (broken), in the second it's a list holding items (works).

**The Question**

Can someone explain the behavior, what's going on under the hood, and ideally how to fix?

**Background of the Real Problem**

The actual code involves the table having a table header (`thead`) section with a title row (`tr`), while the component data appears inside of a table body (`tbody`), and for various reasons I do not want to pollute the page with additional components, nor alter existing component code.

---

**Useful Aside**

And while unrelated, for readers in a similar boat, I discovered by accident `<test/>` and `<test></test>` are not the same thing. In fact, if you take the working case above and try it, you'll discover the last element goes missing. Pop on over to VueJS and read about [self-closing-components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended), as only [official "void" elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) can be self-closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to [DOM template parsing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats) in Vue.js. As mentioned in the docs:

> Some HTML elements, such as `<ul>`, `<ol>`, `<table>` and `<select>` have restrictions on what elements can appear inside them, and some elements such as `<li>`, `<tr>`, and `<option>` can only appear inside certain other elements.

> This will lead to issues when using components with elements that have such restrictions. For example:

> ```
> <table>
> ```

```
   <blog-post-row></blog-post-row>
</table>
```

> The custom component `<blog-post-row>` will be hoisted out as invalid content, causing errors in the eventual rendered output.

This is the exact same issue that you are facing, as `<Test>` is rendered outside the `table` in your demo. Fortunately, the `is` special attribute offers a workaround for this issue. You will simply need to call `<Test>` inside parent component like:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr is="test"></tr>
    <tr><td>Y</td><td>Z</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
const Test = {
  template: '<tr><td>ONE</td><td>TWO</td></tr>'
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Test
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr is="test"></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>Z</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Got it, and that made a lot of sense -- so you're saying the HTML, before VueJS gets involved, hoists up what appears to be an invalid element, and then VueJS does the substitution... that certainly explains it. FYI, the 'is=' solution totally solved it.  Thank you for the working example and the link.  I've been working out of printed books and didn't know what to Google for. This was perfect.

Comment: IMPORTANT: In VueJS 3 the value to is="..." has become v-is="..." using a Javascript expression, meaning you must pass it a string, e.g. <tr v-is="'test'"> with quotes. See v3.vuejs.org/guide/… and also https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/custom-elements-interop.html#v-is-for-in-dom-template-parsing-workarounds for details.