# Why is this simple VueJS 2.x component being hoisted out of the nested HTML table elements?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the development version of VueJS 2.6.12.

In my HTML, I have a VueJS template that looks like this (I've stripped it down for the sake of small examples):

```html
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>AAA</th><th>BBB</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="main">
       <my-item v-for="item in dataset" :d="item" :key="item.key"/>       <!-- (this part works) -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript, I defined a global Vue Component like so (and this works, showing my data):

```js
Vue.component('my-item', {
  props: ["d"],
  template: `<tr><td>{{this.d.AAA}}</td><td>{{this.d.BBB}}</td></tr>`
});
```

When I load the page, I see my data correctly rendered, but the table headers are at the bottom. The `tr` elements (containing my data) are present, though *outside* the `table`.

Viewing the DOM in the browser inspector shows VueJS built this structure, hoisting the elements outside the `tbody` and even the `table` itself:

```html
<div>
  <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>               <!-- Why are these two rows outside the table? -->
  <tr><td>yyy</td><td>zzz</td></tr>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>AAA</th><th>BBB</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="main"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Why is this happening and how can I fix it?**  I'm expecting my <tr>...</tr> elements to be injected within the `tbody` that's under the `thead` header rows.

---

Even slightly stranger, if I manually add in some rows above and below:

```html
    <tbody id="main">
       <tr><td>111</td><td>222</td></tr>
       <my-item v-for="item in dataset" :d="item" :key="item.key"/>
       <tr><td>888</td><td>999</td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

Those *do* get preserved:

```html
<div>
  <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>         <!-- ...but these still got hoisted out if the table -->
  <tr><td>yyy</td><td>zzz</td></tr>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>AAA</th><th>BBB</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="main">
      <tr><td>111</td><td>222</td></tr>
      <tr><td>888</td><td>999</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that an in-DOM template? `<my-item>` is not a valid child element of `<tbody>` and the browser will move it out after parsing the HTML.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, the <my-item> is a Vue Component, which I expected its templating engine to replace it with the set of <tr> elements before injecting into the DOM. But yes, as shown in the answer below, the order or operations is important -- and the source of the problem -- the non-valid child element is hoisted and -afterward- the component is rendered. Hence, the use of a real <tr> element with the is="my-item" attribute to get the desired behavior after-all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ugh, got bit by the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824929/why-is-this-simple-vuejs-component-template-rendering-in-the-incorrect-place-wit), in a slightly different form.*

In a nutshell, there are [DOM Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats), and elements like `table` have restrictions on what elements can appear inside them.  (FYI: `ul`, `ol`, `select` have this issue as well).

The solution is to use VueJS's [`is` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is):

```html
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>AAA</th><th>BBB</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="main">
       <!-- Specify the element, but then use  is="component-name" -->
       <tr is="my-item" v-for="item in dataset" :d="item" :key="item.key"/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This will cause the template parsing to be happy, as `table` (and `tbody`) will be getting a "`tr`" element, but its content will be rendered by the named component.

---

**IMPORTANT**: Breaking change from VueJS 2 (shown above) to VueJS 3.

In VueJS 2 the `is="..."` has become `v-is="..." in VueJS 3.

*Also*, VueJS 2 took a string, where VueJS now takes a Javascript *expression*, meaning you must pass it a string, e.g. `<tr v-is="'my-item'">` with quotes.

See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats and https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#v-is-for-in-dom-template-parsing-workarounds for details.

Comment: Apparently it has changed again in 3.1.0, from [`v-is="'my-item'"`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-is) to [`is="vue:my-item"`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#is)